# Puzzle game using Kinetic js

Tags: javascript, html, puzzle

1. This my code of puzzle game. I just used tutorial code from http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-animals-on-the-beach-game-with-kineticjs/ using Kinetic javascript. I tried to run the code but it doesn't work. I checked error with html and javascript. But I couldn't find what's the problem in my code. 
   Please let me know if there's someone know what's the error which makes it doesn't work.

   ```
   <body>
   <div id="container"></div>
   <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     function loadImages(sources, callback) {
   var assetDir = 'http://citmalumnes.upc.es/~laiafv/zz_MASTER/testhard/images/';
   var images = {};
   var loadedImages = 0;
   var numImages = 0;
   for(var src in sources) {
     numImages++;
   }
   for(var src in sources) {
     images[src] = new Image();
     images[src].onload = function() {
       if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
         callback(images);
       }
     };
     images[src].src = assetDir + sources[src];
   }
   }
   function isNearOutline(country, outline) {
   var c = country;
   var o = outline;
   var cx = c.getX();
   var cy = c.getY();

   if(cx > o.x - 30 && cx < o.x + 30 && cy > o.y - 30 && cy < o.y + 30) {
     return true;
   }
   else {
     return false;
   }
   }
   function drawBackground(background, eumapImg, text) {
   var context = background.getContext();

   context.drawImage(eumapImg, 0, 0);
   context.setAttr('font', '20pt Arial');
   context.setAttr('textAlign', 'center');
   context.setAttr('fillStyle', 'black');
   context.fillText(text, background.getStage().getWidth() / 2, 40);
   }
   function initStage(images) {
   var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
     container: 'container',
     width: 1024,
     height: 668,
   });
   var background = new Kinetic.Layer();
   var countryLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
   var countryShapes = [];
   var score = 0;

   // image positions
   var countries = {
    latvia: {x: 621, y: 198},
    estonia: {x: 640, y: 167},
    czech: {x: 518, y: 344},
    netherlands: {x: 407, y: 292},
     lithuania: {x: 623, y: 230},
     bulgaria: {x: 673, y: 469},
     hungary: {x: 577, y: 389},
     denmark: {x: 474, y: 216},
     austria: {x: 477, y: 388},
     portugal: {x: 182, y: 489}
   };

   var outlines = {
    latvia_black: {x: 621, y: 198},
    estonia_black: {x: 640, y: 167},
    czech_black: {x: 518, y: 344},
    netherlands_black: {x: 407, y: 292},
     lithuania_black: {x: 623, y: 230},
     bulgaria_black: {x: 673, y: 469},
     hungary_black: {x: 577, y: 389},
     denmark_black: {x: 474, y: 216},
     austria_black: {x: 477, y: 388},
     portugal_black: {x: 182, y: 489}
   };

   // create draggable animals
   for(var key in countries) {
     // anonymous function to induce scope
     (function() {
       var privKey = key;
       var anim = countries[key];

       var country = new Kinetic.Image({
         image: images[key],
         x: anim.x,
         y: anim.y,
         draggable: true,
         brightness: 0,
         blurRadius: 0
       });

       country.cache();
       country.drawHitFromCache();
       country.filters([
         Kinetic.Filters.Blur,
         Kinetic.Filters.Brighten
       ]);

       country.on('dragstart', function() {
         this.moveToTop();
         countryLayer.draw();
       });
       /*
        * check if animal is in the right spot and
        * snap into place if it is
        */
       country.on('dragend', function() {
         var outline = outlines[privKey + '_black'];
         if(!country.inRightPlace && isNearOutline(country, outline)) {
           country.setPosition({x:outline.x, y:outline.y});
           countryLayer.draw();
           country.inRightPlace = true;

           if(++score >= 4) {
             var text = 'You win! Enjoy your booty!'
             drawBackground(background, images.eumap, text);
           }

           // disable drag and drop
           setTimeout(function() {
             country.setDraggable(false);
           }, 50);
         }
       });
       // make animal glow on mouseover
       country.on('mouseover touchstart', function() {
         country.blurRadius(1);
         country.brightness(0.3);
         countryLayer.draw();
         document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
       });
       // return animal on mouseout
       country.on('mouseout touchend', function() {
         country.blurRadius(0);
         country.brightness(0);
         countryLayer.draw();
         document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
       });

       country.on('dragmove', function() {
         document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
       });

       countryLayer.add(country);
       countryShapes.push(country);
     })();
   }

   // create animal outlines
   for(var key in outlines) {
     // anonymous function to induce scope
     (function() {
       var imageObj = images[key];
       var out = outlines[key];

       var outline = new Kinetic.Image({
         image: imageObj,
         x: out.x,
         y: out.y
       });

       countryLayer.add(outline);
     })();
   }

   stage.add(background);
   stage.add(countryLayer);

   drawBackground(background, images.eumap, 'Put the countries on the Map!');
   }

   var sources = {
   eumap: 'eumap.png',
   latvia: 'latvia.png',
   latvia_black: 'latvia_shape.png',
   estonia: 'estonia.png',
   estonia_black: 'estonia_shape.png',
   czech:'czechrepublic.png',
   czech_black:'estonia_shape.png',
   netherlands:'netherlands.png',
   netherlands_black:'netherlands_shape.png',
   lithuania: 'lithuania.png',
   lithuania_black:'lithuania_shape.png',
   bulgaria: 'bulgaria.png',
   bulgaria_black:'bulgaria_shape.png', 
   hungary:'hungary.png',
   hungary_black:'hungary_shape.png',
   denmark:'denmark.png',
   denmark_black:'denmark_shape.png', 
   austria:'austria.png',
   austria_black:'austria_shape.png',
   portugal:'portugal.png',
   portugal_black:'portugal_shape.png'
   };
   loadImages(sources, initStage);
   </script>
   </body>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I want you to do is this... change this line to add what I have in BOLD ...

> var outline = new Kinetic.Image({
>         image: imageObj,
>         x: out.x,
>         y: out.y,
>           **draggable: true**
>       });

Then tell me if you are still struggling.

(This will make Latvia draggable, for instance). So you will see the red version of the country under the green version. Hope this is a start at helping.